# Dynamics AX: how to filter a report?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to add a filter to a report in Dynamics AX 2009. Msdn tell me to filter using *Fetch* event. So i've added the following code into the fetch.

DateFromDialog and DateToDialog are variable declared into ClassDeclaration.

```
      qrun = new QueryRun(element);
      _vendInvoiceJour = qrun.get(TableNum(VendInvoiceJour));
      if( _vendInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate <= DateFromDialog.value() ||    _vendInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate  >=DateToDialog.value() ) {
          // Exclude record, don't print it
          return false;
      }
```

Is it correct to return false if the record must not printed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. If your your first record is to be excluded, the `fetch` method return false without sending a single record and nothing is printed.

You can return false in the `send` method. That works but is a poor choice for performance reasons.

The correct way is to add the date range as a query range:

```
SysQuery::findOrAddRange(element.queryrun().query().findDatasource(tableNum(VendInvoiceJour), fieldNum(VendInvoiceJour,InvoiceDate)).value(queryRange(DateFromDialog.value(), DateToDialog.value()));
```

I have not tested the code.